# Dynamic variable in jQuery function parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

Let me explain, I'm using the code bellow to initiate a slideshow:

```
target.cycle({
            timeout: 0,
            before: onBefore,
            after: onAfter,
            next: target + ', #slide-next',
            prev: '#slide-prev'
        })
```

My only problem is I'm having trouble defining the `next` parameter which is supposed to take the selector of the slideshow itself; the variable `target` and the id of `#slide-next`

Unfortunately this code does not work,

when I use `next: '#slide-next',` the slides transition when I press the
 next button, when I use, `next: target,` the slides transition when I
 click on the slides themselves but when I use `next: target + ',#slide-next',` they transition only when I click on the slideshow and not on the next button.

how do I need to define `next`?

Thank you!

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? There's nothing obviously wrong with that code.

Comment: What's the value of `target`?

Comment: I don't think you're using it right, from the docs `next:          null,  // element, jQuery object, or jQuery selector string for the element to use as event trigger for next slide`

Comment: when I use `next: '#slide-next',` the slides transition when I press the next button, when I use, `next: target,` the slides transition when I click on the slides themselves but when I use `next: target + ', #slide-next',` they transition *only* when I click on the slideshow and not on the next button.

Comment: The value of target is a selector string for a div containing a list of images, for example `#slideshow`.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder doesn't the value add up to a selector with a comma in it?

Answer (score 1):

```
var next = target.add("#slide-next");    

target.cycle({
        timeout: 0,
        before: onBefore,
        after: onAfter,
        next: next,
        prev: '#slide-prev'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to set as next, but here is some hint that might help you.

In the element put some attribute that represents a selector of the next element that should be shown e.g.:

```
 <div id="s1" data-next="#s2">...</div>
```

In your initialization put some code that take the current element and use data-next as an attribute for next:

```
target.cycle({
        timeout: 0,
        before: onBefore,
        after: onAfter,
        next: $(target).attr("data-next"),
        prev: '#slide-prev'
    })
```

You will probably need to modify this code but I hope that you see what is idea.

Jovan